# How to add a checkbox dynamically to a table?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Initially, all of them should be false.
I implemented the addition, but it comes out in text in the table, how can I fix it?
[image]

Code:
`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

 table.Columns.Add(" # ");
 table.Columns.Add("");
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; coun < result.Count / 4; i += 4)
{
   coun++;
   table.Rows.Add(new Object[]
  {
  coun,
  new CheckBox(),
  result[i],
  result[i+1],
  result[i+2],
  result[i+3]
 });}`
```

Comment: A `DataTable` - which is what you have - stores data, not any information about how it might be displayed. Perhaps add a `bool` column with `true`/`false` values?

Comment: Instead of a table you can use a datagrid and add a boolean property to an object. It will auto generate the checkbox.

Comment: You might want to consider using WPF. WPF is specifically designed to allow combining controls in almost any way, allowing for great flexibility, at the cost of high learning threshold. Winforms tend to be easier to use as long as you can use the built in controls. But you might need to build your own control from scratch if the built in controls are insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

```
table.Columns.Add("Chk Boxs", typeof(bool));

for (int i = 0; coun < result.Count / 4; i += 4)
{
  coun++;
  table.Rows.Add(new Object[]
{
 coun,
 false,
 result[i],
 result[i+1],
 result[i+2],
 result[i+3]
});}`
```

This boolean is automatically converted to CheckBox